# Start reading from a specific line using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is there anyway using Scanner to start reading the file from a given line.

I want to start reading from the second line to the end of file and excluding the first line.

I have tried this line but it doesn't work

```
String line = input.next("pass the line that I want to start reading from");
```

Any help please

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean that catches the moment of the "starter" value that causes start of reading values.

```
public static final int STARTER = "3";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean read = false;
    try {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = s.nextLine();
            if (!read) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(line) == STARTER) {
                    read = true;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(line); // or save to a list or ...
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works if I want to exclude a specific line in the same code and the same time of reading the file , I need to send a line as a parameter to a function which will start read the file from that line

Answer (score 1):

You can actually create a method to skip the first N lines of the file then read the file normally.

Here is an example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
            skipLines(s, 3);//skip 3 lines of input.txt file
            //read the rest of the file
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = s.nextLine();
                // use lines here
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }

    public static void skipLines(Scanner s,int lineNum){
        for(int i = 0; i < lineNum;i++){
            if(s.hasNextLine())s.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Input.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

output:

```
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: You are welcome :) 
If your problem solved by this answer , just mark it as correct.